# NgIf and @Input Angular 2

Tags: angular, variables

I have problem with passing a variable from parent to child, when the child contains a conditional statement. 
My code looks like this:

Parent:

```
<child-component [eName]="'test1'"></child-component>
```

Child:

```
    @Input() eName = '';
    editState: boolean;

    <div *ngIf="someCondition">
      <div [test]="eName"></div>
    </div>
```

Test is a directive and no matter what goes on in this directive, this example work, when I don't have the condition: `ngIf="someCondition"`. When I have it, it can't properly read the variable `eName`.

How can I change this behavior?

I know that when I change `ngIf` for `ngShow/ngHide` it will work, but I don't want to do it in this way.

Comment: Do you get any errors or `eName` is undefined?

Comment: in your directive, you use the value in constructor or in ngOnInit()?

Comment: No, it's no errors, and when I check value of eName inside onInit, everything is fine -  I have 'test1' here. But at this moment this div isn't present on DOM and it loaded after it so that's the problem.

Comment: Don't force us to guess what the problem could be and what the code could be. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: This is normal behavior of *ngIf directive. Until conditions are met,  eName does not exists. You have to use other way of passing data or check if bool value is true. I had similar problem and what i have done is that i saved bool value to localstorage and retrieve it in ngOnInit(). This was special case at my side so...